# Клиент сервиса Equifax на Java. (CMS/PCS7, Bouncycastle)

Tags: java, шифрование, безопасность

Доброго времени суток!

Есть необходимость реализовать клиент для сервиса кредитной истории "Equifax". Может кто то делал уже, что то подобное - было бы здорово получить ссылочку на исходники или пример реализации.

В инете много чего перерыл, но опыта работы с сертификатами, хранилищами ключей и подписями не очень большой.

Ребята из Equifax говорят следующее:

Для запроса в сервис им нужен подписанный запрос по ГОСТОвскому алгоритму CMS/PKCS7 в DER кодировке.

Насколько я понял, для того чтобы подписать запрос нужен закрытый ключ и сертификат.

У меня есть файл-хранилища ключевой информации, где все это по идее есть. Файлик формате *.pfx.

Удалось из него вытащить сертификат, список элиасов и прочую инфу. Но вот вытащить приватный ключ не выходит.

Привожу пример кода, с помощью которого пытаюсь получить приватный ключ:

```
static final String KEYSTORE_FILE = "C:\\cert_bki.pfx";
static final String KEYSTORE_INSTANCE = "PKCS12";
static final String KEYSTORE_PWD = "pas";
static final String KEYSTORE_ALIAS = "bki";


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, CertificateException, UnrecoverableKeyException, NoSuchProviderException {


    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE_INSTANCE);
    ks.load(new FileInputStream(KEYSTORE_FILE), KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());
    Key key = ks.getKey(KEYSTORE_ALIAS, KEYSTORE_PWD.toCharArray());


}
```

Но при выполнении получаю ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Get Key failed: Cannot find any provider supporting 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.80
at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:410)
at java.security.KeyStore.getKey(KeyStore.java:1023)
at com.mycompany.bki_bouncy.bkiMain.main(bkiMain.java:55)
Caused by: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Cannot find any provider supporting 1.2.840.113549.1.12.1.80
at javax.crypto.Cipher.getInstance(Cipher.java:540)
at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineGetKey(PKCS12KeyStore.java:345)
... 2 more
```

Буду признателен за любую помощь в этом вопросе!